# No funciona roll back codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy realizando una inserción con **Codeigniter 3**, en **MySQL**, misma que funciona bien, la idea es ahora implementar el **rollback**, pero por alguna razón no lo realiza.

Este es mi codigo:

```
$this->db->trans_strict(false);
$this->db->trans_start();

$this->usuario      = $json['usuario'];
$this->clave        = md5($json['claves']);
$this->perfil_id    = $json['perfil_id'];
$this->estado       = $json['estado'];

$this->db->insert('usuario', $this);
$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return false;
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return true;
}
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usando las funciones `$this->db->trans_start();` y `$this->db->trans_complete();` el rollback es automatico si la inserción falla.

Las funciones `$this->db->trans_rollback();` y `$this->db->trans_commit();` son utilizadas para manejar la transacción de forma manual.

Ejemplo de transacción manual:

```php
$this->db->trans_begin();// inicio de transacción manual

$this->usuario      = $json['usuario'];
$this->clave        = md5($json['claves']);
$this->perfil_id    = $json['perfil_id'];
$this->estado       = $json['estado'];

$this->db->insert('usuario', $this);

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
} else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Ref: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually